# Should duplicate questions be deleted by the asker?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

Should duplicate questions be deleted by the asker? It was politely pointed out my question was a duplicate, so I deleted it, then it was I think undeleted, then I edited the question to make it a little different from the duplicate, then it was marked as duplicate.

Not worried, at all, just wondered if deleting was bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may (or should) close or delete your question, if you think your question is a duplicate and especially if the other question already has answers, which answer your question to your satisfaction.

Or, if someone else thinks that your question is a duplicate, and if they close your question, but if you think that your question *isn't* a duplicate, then please comment (or post on Meta) to explain what the difference is between your question and the previous question.

Usually a moderator will close a question if they think it's a duplicate, which has already been answered (and if they close it then there's no need for you to close it). Or if someone is aware of a similar question which isn't an exact duplicate, they'll probably post a comment to say "See also [this other question]" (in which case, again, there's no need for you to close your question).

I think for [this specific question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/21284/254) (which you're asking about), the moderators were undecided about whether it was an exact duplicate (to be closed) or whether it was merely similar. Not your fault!

---

By the way, if a question is closed then there's no need to also delete it. I think the theory is that your (duplicate) question may be phrased slightly differently, and someone search might find your question instead of the original question... and your question will contain a link back to the original question.

See also [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: hmm thanks chrisw, good to know that. don't think i can edit the question into something that isn't duplicate, which is annoying for me. i will try again tho

Comment: Lanka thought the difference might be "Tibetan Buddhism". If you wanted to ask about Tibetan Buddhism you could make that a question, using the [tag:tibetan-buddhism] tag. Perhaps a question like, "Is the doctrine of "rebirth" the same in Tibetan Buddhism as it is in the Pali canon? Is it properly called 'reincarnation', whereas Theravada seems to prefer to call it 'rebirth'? What about the 'bardo'?"

Comment: @user3293056 Or further to [this comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-is-the-difference-between-rebirth-and-reincarnation/21290#comment35117_73) you could ask whether any other religion uses the word "reincarnation" to imply a soul. I think that Hinduism perhaps does? But I'm not sure. That might be a question to ask here or on [Hinduism.SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/) (e.g. "Does Hindu doctrine include 'soul', and 'reincarnation' as opposed to just 'rebirth', and is that known to be a difference between Hindu and Buddhist doctrine?")

Comment: yes i consirdered asking on hinduism.stackexchange too